# Error: Cannot find module '@ionic/app-scripts'

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm new to Ionic. I was following the Ionic documentation "get started", created a project sample named "super". The problem is that when I run the command line `ionic serve` in the project directory, it threw an error `Error: Cannot find module '@ionic/app-scripts'`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

app-scripts currently compatible with node 6 and 7.
İf you installed node 8, then please uninstall and install node 6 stable version.
This solved error and now i can use ionic 3, angular 4 .
Take care!

Comment: hello i am installing  Node v6.11.3 but not work ,still give this error

Comment: After downgrade from 8 to 6 you will need to run npm i @ionic/app-scripts (even if you had run it before) that worked for me

Comment: If you dont want node 8 to be uninstalled, then try this which worked for me .Run this command in terminal 'npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev'

Comment: Thanks @softdevac I just downgraded to node 7.10.1 and it worked like a charm.

Comment: No need to downgrade NodeJS version. running `npm i @ionic/app-scripts` in NodeJS v8 works fine.

Comment: It would be beneficial to include the commands to uninstall the current version of node and install the version needed for convenience.

Comment: Don't downgrade node, instead of that upgrade app-scripts. Using the following command "npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev", it worked for me.

Comment: In my case I had set `NODE_ENV=production` in my terminal. 
To check value of NODE_ENV, `echo $NODE_ENV`, change it back to development with `NODE_ENV=development`.

Comment: @softdevac: sir i am using node 11 version but still got same error what i do sir?

Comment: This answer is not acceptable. Now we have node.js Version 10; we should not downgrade node, instead, we should upgrade that script using " npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev" as others suggested here, then "npm audit fix --force" but I still did not quite get it working using Node V 10.

Comment: Downgrading node is not a solution in 2020. Node v6 or v7  won't even let you run any script without upgrading to a stable LTS version which of course isn't compatible with app-scripts. I managed to get it to work with the current node version, 12. I ran "npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev" first and then "npm audit fix --force". Thanks @J D.

Answer (score 77):

Try installing app-script from npm

npm i @ionic/app-scripts

Comment: this is far more  better solution than downgrading nodejs

Comment: if i will not use sudo then it will  show permission issue .

Comment: @SAJ sir i am using node 11 version but still error what i do sir for fix above error?

Comment: Try to run "npm audit fix --force" after running @Sathyajith command, worked with node v12.18.0.

Answer (score 28):

To get the latest `@ionic/app-scripts`, run the following command:

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Answer (score 19):

do not downgrade the node version, **update** the version of "app-scripts":

*To get the latest @ionic/app-scripts, please run:*

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Answer (score 8):

I was facing same issue, here is what I did-

1. Removed node_modules from directory (Manually).
2. open project dir
3. run this command-

---

```
 npm install
```

That fixed those errors for me.

[See here.](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1764#issuecomment-256114596)

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue , i solved it by deleting node_modules/ folder and ran the command `npm install`now my app works

Answer (score 2):

I tried every non-downgrade solution mentioned in this thread, in all kinds of ways and none of them worked. With nothing left to lose, I went down the  downgrade route (I used `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs` to remove previous 8.x version and then installed the last stable ver on the 6.x branch [using the nodesource ppa](https://joshtronic.com/2017/10/20/upgrade-to-nodejs-8-on-ubuntu-1710/)).

Still got the same errors trying to run in the original project folders, but then I created a new project and `ionic serve` worked just fine in that space.

FWIW, I did not need to run `npm update` or `npm i @ionic/app-scripts` afterwards, but I did find it necessary to adopt the habit of running commands with `sudo` in front (or you `sudo -s` into root account).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and i had problems fixing it. However i update my app scripts `npm install -g @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev` to the latest version and my problem was solved

```js
npm install -g @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Error: ***app-script not found/ app-script not installed/ app-script module is not found***

Try this work for me, Your also:

```
 - npm cache clean --force
   
 - npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
   
 - npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: 2 way check app-script problem
1. ionic info
2. ionic serve

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue, solved by execute `cnpm i @ionic/app-scripts`.

Answer (score 0):

Just open a new terminal window/session. I could not figure it out, but it's probably related to env.

Answer (score 0):

None of the options worked for me.
But I could make it work by updating node with
npm update
After this, the problem was solved and the application started.
Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is what worked for me

I was trying to run the program using VSCode terminal, Instead I used the windows cmd and it ran perfectly. I think the error is in VSCode terminal, it cannot identify the app-scripts module inside the project. Maybe it will be fixed in a later update.

Answer (score 0):

Delete **node_modules** and **package-lock.json**

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
```

Reference: 
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3399

Answer (score 0):

After half a day trying to solve this
And after:
python version error
node-sass misconfiguration error

I did the following

- Remove node-modules folder
- Run "npm audit fix --force"
- Downgrade webpack installation "npm uninstall webpack && install webpack@3.12.0"

The last one because ionic build was giving me an error on that package after the audit

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to set NODE_ENV to production then it installs successfully

```
set NODE_ENV=production
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Answer (score -2):

You must create the project as administrator if you have mac or linux uses sudo, if you have windows run the console as administrator and create the project

Answer (score -3):

My issue was solved after run this script:

```
npm i @ionic/app-scripts
```