# Cannot find module node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts IONIC 3

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic3

I have installed `npm 3.10.10`  then i have `installed ionic 3.9.2` and `cordova 7.0.1`.

i have tried the following steps:

1. `ionic start newProject`

   (selected a tabs project)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. `ionic serve`

this command will `throw` the `error`

> Error: Cannot find module
>   'E:\firstProject\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts'

i found only this thread [Error: Cannot find module '@ionic/app-scripts'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381358/error-cannot-find-module-ionic-app-scripts).

**i don't want to downgrade my nodejs version,as i want to use latest feature**

but i tried,

`npm i @ionic/app-scripts` (**SAG Answer**)

i'm getting same `error` after executing above `command`

**please help me without downgrading `nodejs` `version`**

**EDIT 1 (as per sampath suggestion) :**  below is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "firstProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

when i run `ionic info` it is giving some kind of error

> $ ionic info

[image]

**EDIT 2: (After sampath Answer)**

1. i did the following changes

> ```
> i removed `"@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4"`
> ```

2. > $ npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev

[image]

[image]

[image]

> post $ npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev , package.json
>   file will look like below

[image]

please help me thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Can you show the `package.json` file and `ionic info`?

Comment: hi sampath you can see it at **EDIT1**

Comment: sampath please help me with the above `error`

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I am having the same problem

Comment: In my case I had set `NODE_ENV=production` in my terminal. 
To check value of NODE_ENV, `echo $NODE_ENV`, change it back to development with `NODE_ENV=development`.

Answer (score 8):

Guys i solved this issue. Just want to share with you to save your time at least. Follow steps.

1. Remove `node_modules`.
2. Downgrade Node to version 6 (run `npm install node@6` or `brew install node@6`)
3. Add `"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9"` under dependencies in `project.json`
4. `npm i`

Comment: After struggling with this issue for very long finally, this solution worked.

Comment: @Muhammed: i got above error :after :npm install node@6 but i got above error:npm ERR! node@6.17.1 preinstall: `node installArchSpecificPackage`?

Answer (score 6):

Remove  `"@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4"` from your `package.json` file firstly.

According to your `ionic info`, you have a problem with `app-scripts`.So you can install `latest` as shown below.

and after that compile:

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Remove  `"@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4"` from your `package.json` file firstly.

**Update** [**from Git**](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17261#issuecomment-310797098)

Running on Windows you might try:

1. Set environment in local command window and verify problem:

   `set OPENSSL_CONF=c:\dummy`
   `npm -v`

=> you now probably see this ssl error message

2. Remove environment and verify problem is gone:

   `set OPENSSL_CONF=npm -v`

=> no ssl error message

Comment: hi sampath, i'm still getting the same `error` after following your steps. please look into that, thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the internet on your machine?

Comment: yes i do have i'm able install the `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev` the package

Comment: Can you try **Update** section above? See the git issue too.

Comment: your above update is working, therefore im not getting any junk message in `cosole` . does this solve my original problem?

Comment: OK. You need to run it again the script CLI and see whether is that updated properly on `json` file?

Answer (score 5):

Only install the latest version of @ionic/app-scripts

```html
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

Run:

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-
```

to install `app-script`.

Then:

```
npm install
```

To install `node_modules` to avoid Typescript error

And it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting node_modules folder and do `npm install` again this might solve your problem

Comment: i have tried this but getting same `error`  when i execute `ionic serve`   the error is `Error: Cannot find module 'E:\firstProject\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts`

Comment: i think you should try reinstalling ionic  `npm uninstall ionic -g ` then `npm install ionic -g`

Comment: i have tried that but still same `error`. please help me if have any further solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I tried update npm , reinstall app-script. I uninstalled node and npm, and then installed again  and work it.  I think that error was because the version of npm instaltion was diferent to the original instalation of node