# ionic serve not executing

Tags: node.js, ionic2, linux-mint, ionic-serve

I have this simple app.

I am getting this error while running ionic serve command:

```
Error: Cannot find module 

    '/media/sae/work/linuxspace/techieApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/ionic-angular/app-scripts.js:9:16)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:103:75
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at Object.__awaiter (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:99:16)
        at Object.importAppScripts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/ionic-angular/app-scripts.js:7:20)
```

This link suggests downgrading my node.js.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021115/cannot-find-module-node-modules-ionic-app-scripts-ionic-3
```

I do not want to downgrade my node.js.

Can someone guide me what to do here?

Comment: had same issues too, i had to downgrade to node 6.0.0

Comment: will it work if i downgrade??cant we run with latest node??how can i downgrade my node??

Answer (score 0):

Here you have all versions of Node.js
https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/
Just download the version you want & install it.

from npm docs:

> > **An easy way to stay up-to-date**
> >
> > Node.js has lots of versions, and its development is very active. As a
> >     good practice to manage the various versions, we recommend that you
> >     use a version manager for your Node.js installation. There are many
> >     great options, here are a few:
>
> - NVM
> - nodist
> - n
> - nave
> - nodebrew

Comment: try running this command:      npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev

Comment: can you tell me what's your angular version ?