# Error in Ionic serve

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have this simple app.

I am getting this error while running ionic serve command like this pic:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you are using wrong NodeJS version ionic 3+ is compatible with node 6 and 7 check this question for more explaination

[Error: Cannot find module '@ionic/app-scripts'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381358/error-cannot-find-module-ionic-app-scripts)